# How can I return an array from a method

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

I am working with a project and I need read and save the all file information to the the arrays, Now I want to return one of arrays which is customer Id so that I can add in to another method to search the location.

```
public static int[] booking(int dis) { //dis is in the main method to seanner user input
        
        Scanner date = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputDate;
        if(dis==1) {
            System.out.println("Input the date for the booking");
             inputDate = date.next();
             String str;
             String[] tokens = null;
             int num;
             int line=0;
             int code;
             Booking[] booking = new Booking[20];
             File f = new File("bookings-"+inputDate+".txt");
             try {
                Scanner file = new Scanner(f); //scanner booking file
                
                while(file.hasNext()) {
                    str=file.nextLine();
                    tokens=str.split(",");              
                    booking[line] = new Booking();  // save all values in booking class
                    booking[line].setBookingId(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]));
                    booking[line].setCustomerID(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
                    booking[line].setBookingDate(tokens[2]);
                    for(int i=0;i<tokens[3].length();i++) { //some value in null 
                        if(tokens[3]==null) {
                            tokens[3]="0";
                            }else booking[line].setTotalPrice(Float.parseFloat(tokens[3]));
                    }
                    num=tokens.length-4;
                    int[] intArray = new int[num];
                    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                        
                        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4+i]);
                        
                    }
                    booking[line].setServiceCodes(intArray);
                    line=line+1;
                    
                }
                for(int i=0;i<line;i++) { // the print is works
                //System.out.println(booking[i].getBookingId()+"\t\t"+booking[i].getCustomerID()+"\t\t"+booking[i].getBookingDate()+"\t\t"+booking[i].getTotalPrice()+"\t\t"+Arrays.toString(booking[i].getServiceCodes()));
                    System.out.println(booking[i].getCustomerID());
                    
                }
                
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             
            
        }
        return booking; // the return booking is does not work
        
        
    }
```

How can I call a method and return the arrays I want?

Comment: "the return booking is does not work" `booking` is a `Booking[]`, but the return type of the method is `int[]`.

Comment: Is booking instance a declared class or what. Use int[] instead as its type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method signature, you specify that the method has to return an `int[]`. You are trying to return `booking`, which is of type `Booking[]`. You can change your method signature to return type `Booking[]` instead:

```java
public static Booking[] booking(int dis) {
    ...
}
```

Additionally (as mentioned by OH-GOD-SPIDERS), the `booking` variable is not defined at the point where you use it in the return statement. You can fix this by moving `Booking[] booking = new Booking[20];` above the `if` statement, or by moving the return statement within the `if` statement (adding another return statement for the else case). Which solution you want to pick depends on what you want the method to return in these cases.

Comment: Note that this isn't the only problem. The scope he declared his return variable is different to his return statement resulting in a "booking cannot be resolved to a variable" error.

Answer (score 0):

replace method signature

```
public static int[] booking(int dis)
```

with

```
public static Booking[] booking(int dis)
```

Comment: Note that this isn't the only problem. The scope he declared his return variable is different to his return statement resulting in a "booking cannot be resolved to a variable" error.

Comment: Yea, makes sense, however the answer is not focused on debugging the code, rather it is  answering question asked in the title.

Answer (score 0):

you can't make a function return an array of bookings while the method's return type is an array of int
replace int with booking

Answer (score 0):

The line inside the method while declaring booking. Is booking a type of Booking method.

You cant instantiate a method inside a method so I suggest you turn the property booking to a type of int[] like so:

```
     int[] booking = new int[20];
```

Inside the booking method then you can return booking since your method is a type on int array

Answer (score 0):

booking needs to be declared as an int[], not a Booking[]. Or you need to state Booking[] as return statement.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).